# testEntityManager.persistFlushFind() giving error "detached entity passed to persist"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-test

I was trying to test h2 Repository with spring-boot-testing .Below is the Testing code is used.:

```
package com.santander.Products.Repo;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class ProductRepositoryTest {
    
    @Autowired 
    private ProductRepository repository;
    
    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;
    
    @Test
    public void test_productRpo() {
        Product savedProduct = testEntityManager.persistFlushFind(
                new Product(1,"A","dec",false));
        System.out.println(savedProduct.toString());
        Product product = this.repository.findByName("A");
        Assert.assertTrue(savedProduct.getProductId().equals(product.getProductId()));
    }
}
```

In the above code I am facing this "detached entity passed to persist".

"testEntityManager.persistFlushFind(new Product(1,"A","dec",false))" is giving below error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.santander.Products.Repo.Product
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:726)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:706)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.persist(TestEntityManager.java:92)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.persistAndFlush(TestEntityManager.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager.persistFlushFind(TestEntityManager.java:111)
    at com.santander.Products.Repo.ProductRepositoryTest.test_productRpo(ProductRepositoryTest.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.santander.Products.Repo.Product
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:720)
    ... 37 more
```

Please tell how can i resolve the issue.For more info please comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show your Product entity.

But I assume that the ID is generated with `@GeneratedValue` that's why Hibernate thinks is an existing entity.

You must not set the ID if the ID is generated by Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Error is resolved after not set the ID